# Submitting Values Through AJAX and returning a value

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am having a little difficulty. Basically I am sending information from a form via jQuery and AJAX to MySQL, then returning a value back to my application.

I am able to add the information to my DB but I cant seem to work out how to retrieve the ID of the data inserted. Here is my code -

```
function submitDeliveryDetails(){
    $.ajax({                       
        url: "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mobileapp/add_deliverydetails.php?callback=jsonp1",
        data: addDeliveryData, // Variable holding said delivery information
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                alert(data[index].orderId);
            });                       
        },                     
        error: function(){                       
            //Do Stuff                       
        }
    })
}
```

This sends the information fine. I am able to add to the DB and using the following to return the ID

```
$orderId = mysql_insert_id();
```

I then create JSON format for this value,

```php
$orderIdArray = array('orderId'=>$orderId);
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($orderIdArray).')';
```

When I view this in FireBug, I can see the ID, What I need guidance is how to handle this ID to get it back into my application, As I am getting 'undefined' doing things my way!

Thanks 
Rory

p.s. I am using JSONP as I am dealing with scripts on a separate domain.

Plain text JSON -

```
({"orderId":125})
```

Comment: Could you post the plain text JSON your PHP page is returning.

Comment: Sorry I missed this off, I have added it onto my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous.  That means the ajax call completes and the following functions in your code continue to execute while the ajax call is underway and before it completes.  Therefore, the ONLY place you can do anything with the return value is in the success handler for the ajax function or in any functions you call from there.

This requires changing the flow of your coding, but you need to make the ajax call and then continue the flow of execution in the success handler once the ajax call successfully completes.

Conceptually, it's like this:

```
function submitDeliveryDetails(){
    $.ajax({                       
        url: "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mobileapp/add_deliverydetails.php?callback=jsonp1",
        data: addDeliveryData, // Variable holding said delivery information
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                alert(data[index].orderId);
            });                       
            // you can now continue on here with whatever you wanted to do 
            //    with the the returned JSON data
            // You can operate on the data here or call other functions 
            //    (passing the data as an argument to those functions)
        },                     
        error: function(){                       
            //Do Stuff                       
        }
    })
}

submitDeliveryDetails();
// nothing else to do here because the ajax call has not completed yet
// so the returned results from the ajax call is not available yet
```

Comment: You'd have to show us what the returned JSON looks like and what code you tried.  If the `alert()` inside the `.each()` works, then obviously the data is there so it's just a matter of what code you use to access it.  We can only help further if we know what the data looks like and what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: I have put the JSON as the last part of my question, I am using data[index].orderId inside the alert, this is obviously wrong, so I am trying to work out what it is I put in the alert to simply pop up the number

Comment: If `data` in your success handler is nothing more than `{"orderId":125}`, then you can access the `orderId` with this `data.orderId`.

Comment: I could kiss you! It's worked... It's always something simple where I go wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your submitDeliveryDetails function to take success and error callbacks, then invoke those from the jQuery ajax success and error:

```
function submitDeliveryDetails(options){
    $.ajax({                       
        url: "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mobileapp/add_deliverydetails.php?callback=jsonp1",
        data: addDeliveryData, // Variable holding said delivery information
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            if (options && typeof(options.success) === 'function' ) options.success(data);
        },                     
        error: function(xhr, status, err){                       
            if (options && typeof(options.error) === 'function' ) options.error(xhr, status, err);
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it:

```
submitDeliveryDetails({
    success: function(order) {
       alert(order.orderId);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       // Do Stuff
    }
);
```